# html5 canvas paint application

Tags: html, canvas, paint

I'm working on a paint application with canvas, and trying to make some better tools.
now i have one tool that only connects lines while following the mouse movement.
can you think of a good tutorial or a good idea for other tools like spary, or brush?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a tutorial, but I think you should simply use thicker lines to create a brush tool.

A spray tool could draw random points in a circle with random alpha(that's quite easy to implement), but that might be extremely slow on some browsers. Drawing using pre-generated images would be much better but harder to implement.

Answer (score 8):

You might find the following resources useful:

- [Create a Drawing App with HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/)
- [Create a Paint Bucket Tool in HTML5 and JavaScript](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/)
- [Overview of JavaScript Application Development - Case CanvasDraw](http://nixtu.blogspot.com/2011/04/overview-of-javascript-application.html)
- [Presentation - Intro to HTML5 Canvas](http://nixtu.blogspot.com/2011/06/presentation-intro-to-html5-canvas.html)

Feel free to contact me if you need more specific pointers. I think those above should at least help you to get started. :)

Comment: You got the best answer dude.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this code project article.

it may be useful to you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/427422/Paint-Brush-Application-Using-HTML5-Canvas

thanks